# A couple has 2 children. What is the probability that the couple has one boy and one girl given that they have at least one girl?

Tags: probability, combinatorics, conditional-probability

This is what I have so far:

All possible combinations:

> BB GG BG GB

$P$(Boy $\mid$ Girl)$= 1/2$ given that the sample space is reduced to

> GG and GB

However, I am not sure if this is the right way to approach this question.

Comment: Why are you excluding $BG$?

Comment: Ah, I see. So the solution would be 1/3 because the question says at least 1 girl. Correct?

Comment: The question gets asked routinely here. Did you do a search? E.g., [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1266043/boy-and-girl-paradox-is-driving-me-crazy), [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2163299/probability-at-least-one-boy-vs-exactly-one-boy), [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/395476/given-that-the-family-has-at-least-one-girl-determine-the-probability-that-the), [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3547421/two-children-probability-one-is-a-boy-given-the-other-is-a-boy-conflicting-a)...

Comment: It is: $\mathsf P(\{BG , GB\}\mid \{BG, GB, GG\}) = 2/3$